# Decimal is not validated correctly in MVC 3 with jQuery Validator

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have a property like so `public decimal? MyProperty { get; set; }`, it IS NOT required and IS nullable, but if I don't put a value `> 0` the validator say that the field MyProperty must be a number, if I leave the field empty I receive the same error, and if I put a 0 (zero) I receive the same error.

```
Ex:
0 -> Error
1 -> Ok
0,00 -> Error
0,01 -> Ok
empty -> Error
```

I don't understand why this don't work, I'm using `$.preferCulture("pt-BR");` but don't make sense, because the value `0,01` is accepted, than I don't believe that culture can be the problem.

PS: The validation **don't work in client side**, the server side work correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Default number function has a bug. It test's `parseFloat(value) == 0` and parseFloat for '0' returns 0.

To solve this, I have overwritten it as

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
  return parseFloat(value).toString() !== "NaN";
}
```

I know that isn't the best way, but this workaround solves my problem.

Comment: I found this, and it was quite helpful, but it should probably also have noted that MVC doesn't include the validator code into your code for you, you have to do it yourself.